# Class.forName fails in groovysh where dependency successfully loaded with Grape.grab

Tags: groovy, classloader, groovyshell, groovy-grape

I load the kafka-clients dependency with Grape and can instantiate a StringSerializer, but Class.forName fails. Why is this happening?

```
$ groovysh
Groovy Shell (1.8.6, JVM: 1.8.0_131)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
groovy:000> import static groovy.grape.Grape.grab
===> [import static groovy.grape.Grape.grab]
groovy:000> grab group:'org.apache.kafka', module:'kafka-clients', version:'0.11.0.0'
===> null
groovy:000> new org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer()
===> org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer@2f67b837
groovy:000> Class.forName "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer"
ERROR java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
        at java_lang_Class$forName.call (Unknown Source)
        at groovysh_evaluate.run (groovysh_evaluate:3)
        ...
```

This is frustrating me because instantiating a KafkaProducer apparently requires the Serializer to be able to be loaded from its String class name, even if Serializer instances are passed into the [KafkaProducer constructor](https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html#KafkaProducer(java.util.Properties,%20org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer,%20org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer)).

```
groovy:000> ss = new org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer()
===> org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer@4331d187
groovy:000> producer = new KafkaProducer(props, ss, ss)
ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException:
Invalid value org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer for configuration key.serializer: Class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer could not be found.
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseType (ConfigDef.java:715)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseValue (ConfigDef.java:460)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parse (ConfigDef.java:453)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init> (AbstractConfig.java:62)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init> (AbstractConfig.java:75)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.<init> (ProducerConfig.java:359)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init> (KafkaProducer.java:300)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0 (Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java:423)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke (CachedConstructor.java:77)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor (ConstructorSite.java:102)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor (CallSiteArray.java:54)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor (AbstractCallSite.java:182)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor (AbstractCallSite.java:198)
        at groovysh_evaluate$_run_closure1.doCall (groovysh_evaluate:7)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke (CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke (MetaMethod.java:233)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod (ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod (MetaClassImpl.java:877)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing (MetaClassImpl.java:1093)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod (MetaClassImpl.java:1049)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod (MetaClassImpl.java:877)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent (PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent (CallSiteArray.java:46)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent (AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent (AbstractCallSite.java:141)
        at groovysh_evaluate.run (groovysh_evaluate:4)
        ...
```

I'm looking for a workaround that would get Class.forName working, or any oher way to avoid the ConfigException (caused by a ClassNotFoundException).

Comment: Cannot reproduce it in my computer.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you use groovy `1.8.6`? I have just followed all your steps using groovysh `2.4.12` and it worked - https://asciinema.org/a/IdNu0xuI4KxFtj6EWRPu5N7U2

Comment: `1.8.6` is what `apt-get install groovy` installed. But I upgraded to `2.3.12` and while `Class.forName` on the shell works, I get the same stack trace attempting to construct a KafkaProducer.